# Issue removing front of dequeue (Double ended queue)

Tags: java, data-structures

I am tasked with creating a Deque in java with options to add left, add right, remove left and remove right.

I have coded the add right and remove right methods successfully however I have issues trying to get add left and remove left working.

I think I have gone massively wrong somewhere. I have just tried swapping round the variables for add left and reversing the calculations which did not work and would just come up with the following :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332) 
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137) 
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121) 
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421) 
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265) 
at datastructuresass1.DendQueue.toString(DendQueue.java:107) 
at datastructuresass1.main.main(main.java:21) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I am trying to create the deque using arrays. Below is my code for the add right and add left methods:

Add Left (which is not working)

```
public void addLeft(T o){

         left = (left + 1) % arr.length;
         arr[left] = o;

        // if the array is full copy it to a larger one
        if ((left + 1) % arr.length == right) {
            T[] newarr = (T[]) new Object[arr.length * 2];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                newarr[i] = arr[(right - i) % arr.length];
            arr = newarr;
            left = i - 1;
            right = 0;

            System.out.println("Array size increased to " + 
            arr.length);
        }
```

Add Right (Which is working)

```
public void addRight(T o) {
        right = (right + 1) % arr.length;
        arr[right] = o;

        // if the array is full copy it to a larger one
        if ((right + 1) % arr.length == left) {
            T[] newarr = (T[]) new Object[arr.length * 2];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                newarr[i] = arr[(left + i) % arr.length];
            arr = newarr;
            left = 0;
            right = i - 1;

            System.out.println("Array size increased to " + 
            arr.length);
        }
```

Please could someone explain to me why this addLeft method is not working. It would be a great help as I have been stumped on this for a while! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Working with an array is very inefficient, try a linkedlist, much easier! 
And way more appropriate (much faster) for a queue as it does not need all the memory copying for adding and removing objects. It has methods for addfirst and addlast etc.

LinkedList is part of the standard Java library: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Doubly_linked_list for how it works

If your teacher forces you to use an array, than he is nuts :D

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the variables won't be enough.

Looks like the `left` calculation seems wrong: `left = (left + 1) % arr.length;`. You shouldn't be incrementing, rather decrementing it. Unlike `right`, you use modulus (`%`) operator to wrap back to `0`. But `left` will have to make do with simple `if` conditions.

```
if (left - 1 < 0)          //if left is going less than zero, 
    left = arr.length - 1; //wrap it back to the end of the array
else
    left = left - 1;      //else do normal decrement
arr[left] = o;

// if the array is full copy it to a larger one
// if left is at the begining & right's at the ending, then we're full
if ((left == 0 && right == arr.length - 1)
    // or if decrementing leftwards reaches right, we're full
    || left - 1 == right) {
```

In the array copying loop, regardless of whether adding right or left made the array full, the copying logic will remain same. You just need to copy all the elements from `left` to `right` into the new array from `0` to `2n`. So, no need to swap variables in the array copying logic. You can re-use the logic in `addRight()`.

Hopefully that helps in getting in the right direction. I won't be able to reproduce the error that you faced until you provide complete code + the test case that triggered that error.

If you're not aware already, there's an implementation of Deque using circular array [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-deque-using-circular-array/). You could study & understand where & why you went wrong. Also, adding to front/rear sound less confusing than right/left. :)